# Google Chrome JQuery console output

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just got started with jquery, and rather than the expected output of `[<li>my name</li>,` Google chrome console outputs:

> [li, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
>   0
>   :
>   li
>   length
>   :
>   1
>   prevObject
>   :
>   r.fn.init(1)
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Object(0)

```
<html>
<head>

<title>fww</title>

</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li>my name</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var lis = jQuery('ul li');
    console.log(lis);
</script>
</body>

</html>

 <html>
    <head>

    <title>fww</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <ul>
        <li>my name</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var lis = jQuery('ul li');
        console.log(lis);
    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there really an effort made prior to ask?

Comment: obviously there was, a console.log was used.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is exactly what should be returned! You have done nothing wrong. You cast your 'ul li' as a jQuery object when you did this:

```
jQuery('ul li');
```

What you are seeing in console is the jQuery object being printed out - including all inherited properties and methods that are part of that jQuery object. If you want to print out individual properties, you have to use the methods that come as part of the jQuery object. For example, if you want to print the text in that li element, you would just add

```
.text()
```

to the end of the object. Like this:

```
jQuery('ul li').text();
```

or  if you want to know how many li element their are, you could do:

```
jQuery('ul li').length();
```